# How to run apkfile in application

Tags: android, apk

This code is running an apkfile after download from webserver.

But..
When the apkfile runs, it prints this message.

-Parse error
"There is a problem parsing the package."

When i run apkfile after copy to device, it did not print message.

How can I solve this ?

p.s) starting method is skinDownload(filename).

```
    String File_Name = "";   
String File_extend = "";   

String fileURL = "http://URL/";
String Save_Path = "/data/data/kr.appsol.util.calc.formcalc/themes";   

DownloadThread dThread;  
ProgressDialog downDialog = null;


private void skinDownload(String filename){

    File_Name = filename + ".apk";
    File_extend = "apk";

    File dir = new File(Save_Path);

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }

    if (new File(Save_Path + "/" + File_Name).exists() == false) {
        downDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity_SkinList.this, "", getString(R.string.setting_skin_downloading));
        downDialog.show();
        dThread = new DownloadThread(fileURL + "/" + File_Name,
                Save_Path + "/" + File_Name);
        dThread.start();
    } else {
        showDownloadFile();
    }



}

class DownloadThread extends Thread {
    String ServerUrl;
    String LocalPath;

    DownloadThread(String serverPath, String localPath) {
        ServerUrl = serverPath;
        LocalPath = localPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        URL imgurl;
        int Read;
        try {
            imgurl = new URL(ServerUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imgurl
                    .openConnection();
            int len = conn.getContentLength();
            byte[] tmpByte = new byte[len];
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            File file = new File(LocalPath);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            for (;;) {
                Read = is.read(tmpByte);
                if (Read <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                fos.write(tmpByte, 0, Read);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR1", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR2", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mAfterDown.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}

Handler mAfterDown = new Handler() { 
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        downDialog.dismiss();

        // run
        showDownloadFile();
    }

};

private void showDownloadFile() {

    File apkFile = new File(Save_Path + "/" + File_Name);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to flush the stream before closing it:

```
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```